# is Blaze fully integrated with Meteor by default or must it be added manually?

Tags: meteor-blaze

I'm trying to render attributes of an svg according to several properties assigned to the 'card' object instances in my 'Card' Collection. I've never used Blaze explicitly before, I'm just curious if I need to add it as a package or whether it's functionality is now built into the latest Meteor version.

```
<template name="card">
  <div class="card svg">
    <!-- <svg class="symbol" style="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 768">
      <path d="M511.9 184l-100 200 100 200 100-200" />
    </svg>
    {{#each cards}}
     {{> svgType this}}
   {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="svgType">
  {{#each svgTypes }}
  <svg class="color shape quant fill">
    {{> UI.dynamic template=this}}
  </svg>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

---and then I have a list of templates in an array similar to the approach taken here: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/

So I'm making a template for the color, shape, quantity, and fill of the svg(s) rendered to each card-- then using the svgType template to render them according to my logic (ie, if (card.color === 'r', svg.color = '#12345)

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide here...